# Copy + Paste Chinese From Website

Tags: fonts, notepad++, encoding, language

I am re-branding a website that has both English & Chinese Traditional text. When I am copying + pasting the Chinese text into notepad++, the characters gets displayed as question marks. I tried changing the language settings within notepad++ to Chinese, but it now displays as squashed rectangles. I also changed my keyboard language setting in Windows 7 to Chinese but it did not work.

This is what I see when I right-click in Chrome to copy the Chinese character:
[image]

Comment: I would love to know if this got solved.  I'm copying/pasting Chinese characters from a Word document into Notepad++, and Notepad++ is the only one that renders the characters incorrectly.  My browser, other text editors, etc, all work fine, and YES Global Font and UTF-8 without BOM is selected in Notepad++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This thread seemed to at least damper my problem:

[How to display chinese characters on Notepad?](https://superuser.com/questions/211378/how-to-display-chinese-characters-on-notepad)

Apparently, even though Notepad++ is storing the characters correctly, they are not being displayed correctly.

You can use one of the newly supported fonts (ver.6) under **Settings > Style Configurator > Font Style > Font Name** , the ones at the top, that support Chinese character display.  So long as the file is encoded `UTF-8`, it will display correctly either way, you just may have to see squares instead of the actual characters when editing.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using **Notepad++**, be sure to set the **Encoding** to `UTF-8` when dealing with non-ANSI characters (e.g. Chinese).

[image: encoding]

---

Also, you can verify the encoding of the page you are working with, and set Notepad++'s encoding to match. If you are using Firefox, the encoding can be found in the **Page Info** popup accessed by clicking the webpage's **favicon**.

[image: page info]

---

If changing the encoding does not resolve the issue, it may be that Notepad++ is using a font that does not support all characters for that encoding. Change the font by going to **Settings > Style Configurator** and setting the **Global Font** to a [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typefaces#Unicode_fonts) or proper typeface. *(I use [DejaVu Sans Mono](http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/Main_Page).)*

[image: settings]

[image: global font]

Comment: I looked at the encoding of the source and it is Big5, and not Unicode. I modified notepad++ to Big5, but I'm still getting squashed squares when I copy + paste.

Comment: Which font are you using in Notepad++? See my updated answer.

Comment: My settings are the same as yours except I did not have 'enable global font' checked. With your settings, I now get a question mark instead of a squashed square. Could there be a problem with my browser as I only see squares under the copy selector (see my updated question).

Comment: Moving coding from ansi to utf-8 in notepad++ solved it for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Chinese text can be copy/pasted normally in Windows 7.  It sounds to me like you're using a program that isn't Unicode-aware.  As an experiment I opened up a text file (using plain old Notepad) that contains Chinese in Windows 7, copied a line and pasted it into this message which is inside a virtual machine running XP with the east Asian fonts installed.  It worked.

Comment: I tried doing that in Notepad but I still got squashed squares. When I right-click on a Chinese character in Chrome, it says 'Search Google for []' where [] = square.

Comment: @icu222much - This confirms Loren's theory.

Comment: I looked at the encoding of the source and it is Big5.

Answer (score 0):

I tried changing fonts, encoding and other suggested stuff but couldn't resolve the issue.

Creating a new user account in my windows 7 resolved the issue for me, I thought I'd have to move all the data from that account to the newly created account.

But surprisingly, it fixed the issue in the previous account also, so I deleted the new account using the old one without any problem.

Give it a try, hope that helps someone having the same issue.