# What are these unknown symbols that show up in my HTML when using Notepad?

Tags: notepad, utf-8, symbols

These characters can be found by me in Notepad when writing HTML. It absolutely causing problems for me. I can’t even delete it!

So does anyone knows this symbol is or why it appears? I’ve tried to Google it, and it can’t find it.

My HTML is as follows:

```
<td class="ti"> 冰箱 </td>
<td> bīng xiāng </td>
<td> Freezer </td>
```

And here are two screenshots to show you what I am seeing.

This is what it looks like in Firefox:

[image: Firefox]

And this is what it looks like in Google Chrome:

[image: Google Chrome]

Comment: Which input method / locale are you using?

Comment: It was copy and paste the chinese characters or type them in, then switch to english input.

Comment: It may be Unicode character [`U+001E`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/001e/browsertest.htm) which led me to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23232692/what-is-a-rs-in-a-htmltext-file. It seems they faced a similar issue and I've experienced this too when copying between different applications. If I copy `001E` from that page into Notepad++ I see the `RS` symbol. Try copying the whole line of code into a hexadecimal editor like https://hexed.it/ and see what you get. Are there two `1E` characters before where `class` begins?

Comment: Yes, but I can't delete them. Also they were edited by one Notepad, so there isn't a problem of copying.

Comment: They are invisible and the only way to notice is if you scroll through the code with arrow keys, and there is a delay.I checked it, and they are `1E` (without the zeroes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When saving text files using Notepad, the default text encoding format is set to ANSI. On the other hand, if you open a text file in an application that's using a different encoding, the computer displays whatever the character corresponds to.

Converting the file from ANSI encoding to UTF-8 will remove the incorrect formatting. In Notepad select *File* -> *Save As*, choose *UTF-8* from the dropdown menu next to *Encoding*, change the font to Times New Roman in order to save the Chinese characters properly, and click the *Save* button. Your file will be converted and saved in the UTF-8 format.

<sub>[How to display Chinese characters on Notepad?](https://superuser.com/q/211378)</sub>

Comment: You cannot enter Chinese characters unless it is an unicode format. I chose UTF-8.

Comment: Next, I don't know how those `001E` got there, and saving it in unicode will save those characters, because they can be represented by Unicode (UTF-16, don't use this because it causes problem when uploading to sites), but I use UTF-8 (which saves it as well).

Comment: Times New Roman font works in Notepad for Chinese character with UTF-8 encoding, but the default Lucida Console font doesn't work in Notepad with UTF-8.

Comment: It is set to Consolas, and even if it is the default font, they will switch the font so they can display it.